# Syntax Tree in Eclipse for C code

Tags: java, c, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm trying to implement a plug-in for Eclipse (using Java) for C programmers, in which the user could right click on any variable in his/her C code and I would give him all sorts of information on that variable (like usages or which function is it passed to ... etc.).

Do you know how can I achieve this? If so - can I get the C syntax tree ?

Are there any open source project I could use as a reference ?

Comment: How does what you want to do differ from what Eclipse's own CDT already provides?

Comment: Consider asking for tools at http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/ask

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer to your question, but have you heard of the program Doxygen (also has an eclipse plugin? Take a look and see if it meets your needs. Sometimes it is easier to use pre-existing plugins rather than creating your own.